# How to combine multiple list to create nested in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a number of lists `[1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9]`. How do I get the output as `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` using [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir)?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
IO.inspect(a, label: "a_data")
```

You will find `a` is already `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`, no need any `transform` code.